# obj c: accessor: self vs myInstance

Tags: objective-c, self, accessor

In Apple's The Objective-C Programming Language p. 18, they make a distinction between setting a variable with self versus instance reference. e.g 
myInstance.value =10;
self.value =10;
1. Would these two set different properties named value?
2. How could self work if there are several instances with properties named value?
They also assert, "If you do not use self., you access the instance variable directly." This would mean that the accessor would not be called if you use 
myInstance.value =10;
and KVO wouldn't work. Is this true?
3. Using @Property and @Synthesize (with garbage collection), what is the proper way to set properties of different instances? And what good is the self reference?
A numeric example would help me, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My big problem was how an ivar and a property could be tied together when they have different names, especially with multiple ivars.
I finally found that if name of property doesn't match name of ivar, a new ivar is synthesized. This is accessed by self.propertyname (within object) or object.propertyname (outside of object), not the declared ivar.

To tie disparate names of ivar and property, equate them as in
@synthesize propertyname = ivarname.

Thanks to

http://blog.ablepear.com/2010/05/objective-c-tuesdays-synthesizing.html

Answer (score 2):

**1 - Would these two set different properties named value?**

No, I think you misunderstand what [the guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/ObjC.pdf) is saying when it makes a distinction between self.value and myInstance.value.  In both cases the setter function (i.e., setValue:) is called.

You use self to access your own properties (that is, referencing properties from within functions in a class that you wrote).  Like:

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject
@property( nonatomic ) NSInteger value;
- (void) doSomething;
@end


@implementation MyObject

@synthesize value;

- (void) doSomething
{
    self.value = 10;
}

@end
```

Whereas you'd use myInstance to set a property in some other variable, from outside that class.

```
MyObject* anObject = [[MyObject alloc] init];
anObject.value = 10;
```

**2 - How could self work if there are several instances with properties named value?**

It wouldn't.  See above.

**They also assert, "If you do not use self., you access the instance variable directly." This would mean that the accessor would not be called if you use myInstance.value =10; and KVO wouldn't work. Is this true?**

No.  self.value and myInstance.value both call their accessors (setValue: in this case), and KVO will work.  What that assertion means is that if you access an ivar from within your own class, not using the accessor, KVO will not work.

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject
@property( nonatomic ) NSInteger value;
- (void) doSomething;
@end


@implementation MyObject

@synthesize value;

- (void) doSomething
{
    self.value = 10;    // This invokes the accessor, and KVO works.
    value = 10;  // This just sets the instance variable, and KVO won't work.
}

@end
```

**Using @Property and @Synthesize (with garbage collection), what is the proper way to set properties of different instances? And what good is the self reference? A numeric example would help me, please.**

Just as shown above, use the instance name.  self is only used for accessing properties within a class.  Examples above.

Comment: Thanks to all, I think I understand when there's only one ivar with one property, but not when there are two ivars, each with a property that has the same name.

Comment: (I hope I'm using the formats here correctly.)    Thanks to all, I think I understand when there's only one ivar with one property, but not when there are two ivars, each with a property that has the same name.  Example: ivars coin1, coin2; @property value;.  Within MYObject, I can't say coin1.value = 5; coin2.value = 10;.  So how can I set the values, using accessors?  It seems ridiculous to set up another object and do the setting from there.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to under stand self is to think of how it is implemented, as a hidden argument with every method call so the method -[UIView drawRect:] has a c function implementation like

```
BOOL drawRect:( UIView * self, SEL _cmd, NSRect r ) { };    // of cause : is not legal in c
```

and calling the method is a little like (ignoring the dynamic look up)

```
UIView  * v = ...
NSRect  r = ...

drawRect:( v, @selector(drawRect:), r );
```

so if you invoke a property in the drawRect: implementation you are doing it for the hidden object parameter called self.

Accessing the instance variable directly will stop KVO from working, but sometimes you want that, for example when initialising them perhaps.

IF you mean automatic reference counting when you say Garbage Collection, most of the time for objects you want them to be strong or copy, immutable strings using copy will be turned into a retain and if it is mutable then you often want a copy to protect against the original being changed underneath you.

One potential issue with strong is that you can end up with circular references where if you follow the links around you comeback to the original object so each object is indirectly retaining itself and you have a catch-22 situation where the object has to release itself before it can release itself. So in these situations you need to use weak. You can usually workout who should retain and who should weak by think about which object conceptually owns the other.

For non-object you have to use assign.

Answer (score 0):

`self.property` and `[self method];` are strictly used within a class to refer to itself. You do not **ever** refer to the object within itself with anything but `self`.

On the contrary, use instances of an object to refer to an object from another class. For instance, I would refer to a `UIImageView` from my `viewController` in a way like:

```
UIImageView* imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
[imgView setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];
```

But if I were editing a subclass of UIImageView that I called, say rotatingImageView:

```
@implementation rotatingImageView

-(id)init
{
    //Super instantiation code that I don't remember at the moment goes here
    [self setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];
}
```

This is just an example of a method.

Once again, you use self strictly within its own class, and you use other variables to reference an instance of another class.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I'm still missing something: if there are two or more instances of an object with the same named property (say, value), how would self.value know which one to use?